# Google Map API V3 detecting container width/height change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to detect when a maps container has changed so that I can run `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` but I can't seem to get it to work. Is there a Listener to detect when the container has changed size? I know it doesn't work as the map will have a section which is greyed out.

I have trie the following but all seem to fail when the container size has changed, `bounds_changed` works when the map is dragged by my cursor.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'resize', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

**map declaration and init()**

```
var map, mapOptions, mapElement,valMap,valZoom;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
function init() {
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.697299 , -73.809815),
        panControl:true
    };
    mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    mapCenter();
    mapZoom();
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        mapCenter();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        mapZoom();
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

}

**key up resize**

```
$("#width, #height").keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
        size();
    }, 500 );
        console.log('0');
        mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
        console.log(mapElement);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener( mapElement, 'resize', function(e){
            console.log( 'Resize', e);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            console.log('1');
        });
        console.log('2');
});
```

Comment: What's your declaration for map?

Comment: @LaughDonor please see the OP again

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using something like `google.maps.event.addDomListener( mapElement, 'resize', function(e){console.log( 'Resize', e)} );`?

Maybe the listener for the Map object doesn't support `'resize'`.

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqn6D/)

Comment: add `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` into the function and you will have it.

Comment: @LaughDonor Check my edit, `console.log('0'); console.log(mapElement); console.log('2');` all work but `console.log( 'Resize', e); console.log('1');` don't show up in the console log which I think means they didn't fire

Comment: I know this may be an obvious question, but did you try resizing the `#map` DOM element to watch for response?

Comment: @LaughDonor each piece I found on Google couldn't get resize detection to work. had to settle for http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Comment: Weird, cause I've tested it to work on my end. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqn6D/)